# Doubleclick on QTreeView shall always return first columns value

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview

I have my **QTreeView** where whole rows were selected:

```
  ui->treeView->setSelectionBehavior (QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

...and already filled with ID-Number <--> Description. All are structured as a tree. I can click it, and retreive corresponding selection via:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText( modelIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString() );
```

and I already connected:

```
  connect(ui->treeView, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(onSelectedTreeView(QModelIndex)));
```

When I click on a ID-Number, it works perfectly, and my modelIndex.data() returns the ID-Number.

When I click on the description, my `modelIndex.data()` returns its correct description (second column). BUT I would like to have again the corresponding ID-Number (first column).

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to use QAbstractItemModel for that purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sibling(int row, int column)` method of `QModelIndex`

In python:

```
def onSelectedTreeView(index):
    firstColumnIndex=index.sibling(index.row(),0)
    print(firstColumnIndex.data())
```

I guess you could do:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(modelIndex.sibling(modelIndex.row(),0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change treeView `selectionBehavior` to `SelectItems`. Than use index.row() and index.column().. And dont forget that it always start from 0

```
onSelectedTreeView()
{
    //Put all your selected indexes into QModelIndexList
    QModelIndexList _indexes = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();

    // For each loop for every selected index.. 
    foreach (QModelIndex index, _indexes)
    {

    //if your index data == 0 it means that you clicked into ID-number field.

   //So you can easly see which index you clicked with qdebug
   qDebug() << "Row = " << index.row() << "\t Column = " << index.column();

   // So if you want to get always index of first column(ID-Number) use QAbstractItemModel
   if(index.column().toInt() != 0 ) //if your index not equal to 0
   {
      const QAbstractItemModel* absModel = index.model();

      // change index of absModel from index.column() to 0;
     QModelIndex changedIndex = absModel->data(absModel->index(index.row(), 0), Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();

     qDebug() << "Row = " << changedIndex.row() << "\t Column = " << changedIndex.column();
   }

   }
}
```